# How to pass in the fieldname to filter in django?

Tags: django

Filtering in Django is pretty straight forward if you know which fieldname you are filtering for:

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
```

But if I would like to pass in the "headline" fieldname it gets more difficult:

```
kwargs = {request.GET['fieldname'] : request.GET['query']}
Entry.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

the problem with the solution above is though, how do I pass in the `__startswith` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kwargs = {"%s__startswith" % (request.GET['fieldname']) : request.GET['query']}
Entry.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```